# copy a worksheet from one excel workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a two excel spreadsheets i need to copy a worksheets with its data and paste it to another workbook.

while executing the code its not copying the sheet to another workbook. If i modified my code and excute thrice or twice its copying twice in target workbook.
Can someone help me out.

Code:

```
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim RB_Filename As String
Dim RB_workbook As Workbook
Dim Master_workbook As Workbook
Dim RB_sheet As Worksheet
Dim Master_sheet As Worksheet
Dim errSheet As Worksheet
Dim errSheetExists As Boolean
Dim StatusSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceStatusSheet As Worksheet


Set Master_workbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get the  workbook
filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
MsgBox "Please insert file "
RB_Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

'If Cancel then exit
If TypeName(RB_Filename) = "Boolean" Then
Exit Sub
End If

Set RB_workbook = Workbooks.Open(RB_Filename
Set RB_sheet = RB_workbook.Worksheets("Holger")
RB_sheet.Activate
RB_sheet.Select
For Each sourceStatusSheet In Master_workbook.Worksheets
            If sourceStatusSheet.Name = "Holger" Then
                Windows(Master_workbook.Name).Activate
                Master_workbook.Sheets(sourceStatusSheet.Name).Select

                'Worksheets(i).Cells.ClearContents
                 sourceStatusSheet.Delete
                 RB_sheet.Copy After:=Master_workbook.Sheets(Master_workbook.Sheets.Count)
                 Master_workbook.Activate

            Exit For
            End If
        Next
If TypeName(RB_sheet) = "Boolean" Then
Exit Sub
End If
RB_workbook.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is best to simply try and [.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837404.aspx) something whether it exists or not. `On Error Resume Next` can skip over trying to delete something that doesn't exist and [Application.DisplayAlerts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782.aspx) can skip any annoying confirmations if it does.

```
Sub ws_Copy()
    Dim filter As String
    Dim caption As String
    Dim RB_Filename As String
    Dim RB_workbook As Workbook
    Dim Master_workbook As Workbook
    Dim RB_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Master_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim errSheet As Worksheet
    Dim errSheetExists As Boolean
    Dim StatusSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceStatusSheet As Worksheet


    Set Master_workbook = ActiveWorkbook

    ' get the  workbook
    filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
    caption = "Please Select an input file "
    MsgBox "Please insert file "
    RB_Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

    'If Cancel then exit
    If TypeName(RB_Filename) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub

    Set RB_workbook = Workbooks.Open(RB_Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set RB_sheet = RB_workbook.Worksheets("Holger")

    With Master_workbook
        'first remove the Holger ws from Master (if it exists)
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Worksheets("Holger").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0

        'copy the Holger ws to Master
        RB_sheet.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    End With

    RB_workbook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: @jeepad its working absoultely fine. I really appreciate your work

Comment: Glad that worked out. You might want to edit the GetOpenFilename filter though. I don't know too many Text files that have the **.xlsx** file extension.  :)

Comment: @jeepad Is there any way to change 'Activeworkbook' beacuse if i open the original files the data is populating into the original files as well as activeworkbook? could you please let me know.

Comment: There is the [ActiveWorkbook property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx) and [ThisWorkbook Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215773.aspx). Additionally, you can reference with the [Workbook.Names property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.names.aspx) in the [Workbooks Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224505.aspx).

Comment: @jeepad could you please look over the below link . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127292/delete-unwanted-similar-columns-across-multiple-workbooks-in-vba-excel